# how to upload video to youtube from an URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube

in my app i want to upload an video to youtube. The video is already been placed in another database of an URL. How to upload the video from that url to youtube......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code in [this test application](http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/) and just change the path of the file from `nsString` to `nsUrl`. 
But you have to use the new version of http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Here is a [good tutorial](http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/). It works like charm. I can now upload video both from the device and an URL.

Answer (score 4):

YouTube does not provide an API to upload videos from a URL.  You would first have to download the video to your device.  Once you have video, the actual file, you can upload the video to YouTube using their API.

You would have use NSURLConnection and or NSURLRequest to upload the video.
[Browser-based uploading](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Browser_based_uploading)